# How do I disable gravity for my android app

Tags: android, layout-gravity

See I have this android app and I kinda designed it using absolute positioning of elements so when I turn my phone 90 degrees the look is completely messed up. How I do I force my app to not change the layout when I turn my phone !

Comment: Do you want to lock the orientation to portrait?

Comment: Yes ! I want the orientation to lock to potrait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the activity in your manifest.

Comment: There is a file called `AndroidManifest.xml` in your project.

netbeans isn't normally used for Android development though. I suggest Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet in your situation is to probably only allow a portrait orientation. You can do this in your AndroidManifest.xml with the following definition;

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.SampleActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```